# Type cast issue in java (ascii value to char)

Tags: java, casting

The problem I am facing occurs when I try to type cast some ASCII values to `char`.

For example:

```
(char)145 //returns ? 
(char)129 //also returns ?
```

but it is supposed to return a different character. It happens to many other values as well.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: ASCII is only defined for values below 128, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a 7-bit encoding system. Some programs even use this to detect if a file is binary or textual. Characters below 32 are escape characters and are used as directives (for instance new lines, print command)

The program however will still work. A character is simply stored as a short (thus sixteen bits). But the values in that range don't have an interpretation. This means that the **textual output** of both values will lead to nothing. On the other hand comparisons like `(char) 145 == (char) 129` will still work (return false). Simply because for a processor, there is no difference between a short and a character.

---

If you are interested in converting your value such that only the lowest seven bits count (this modifying the value such that it is in the valid range), you can use masking:

```
int value = 145;
value &= 0x7f;
char c = (char) value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The char type is Unicode 16 bit, UTF-16. So you could do `(char) 265` for c-with-circumflex. ASCII is 7 bits 0 - 127.

```
String s = "" + ((char)145) + ((char)129);
```

The above is a string of two Unicode characters (each 2 bytes, UTF-16).

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); // ASCII with '?' as 7bit
s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); // "??"

byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // ISO-8859-1 with Latin1

byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("Windows-1252"); // With Windows Latin1

byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // No information loss.
s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_9); // Orinal string.
```

In java `String/char/Reader/Writer` tackle text (in Unicode), whereas `byte[]/InputStream/OutputStream` tackle binary data, bytes.

And for bytes must always be associated with an encoding to give text.

**Answer:** as soon as there is a conversion from text to some encoding that does not represent that char, a question mark can be written.

Answer (score 0):

These expressions evaluate to true:

```
((char) 145) == '\u0091';
((char) 129) == '\u0081';
```

These UTF-16 values map to the [Unicode code points](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) U+0091 and U+0081:

```
0091;<control>;Cc;0;BN;;;;;N;PRIVATE USE ONE;;;;
0081;<control>;Cc;0;BN;;;;;N;;;;;
```

These are both control characters without visible graphemes (the question mark acts as a substitution character) and one of them is private use so has no designated purpose. Neither are in the ASCII set.